# Process (not remove) carriage return (^M) characters?

Tags: text-processing

Is there a way to read in and process control characters like `^M` and only show the final output? For example, I have the following string:

```
track^Mfl^Ms
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
slack
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: `col -b` should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already mentioned in the comments but it probably should be the answer:

> `col -b` should help

Comment: Note that `\r`/`^M` is not the only control character/sequence it recognises. The BSD one (often the one also found on Linux-based systems) interprets the input as a Teletype Model 37 would (not like modern terminals would). In particular SPC does not erase, it moves the cursor forward one position, so `abc\rA C` would render as `AbC`, not `A C`.